# Multiple redux stores or combineReducers for similar forms?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a landing page that contains 3 different forms.  As of right now, the landing page doesn't necessarily need to be connected to redux, the data is static and won't change.  However, the forms fetch data and allow for a user to filter down the options based on a particular service that they correspond with and are connected to redis.  The forms are nearly identical in their appearance and functionality but all fetch different endpoints.

To help me explain here is a crude rendering of the forms.  The s# is a select drop down and the button is basically a link that takes the user to a page with more information for the values selected.

```
|------------|
|    FORM    |
|------------|
|-----s1-----|
|-----s2-----|
|-----s3-----|
|--[button]--|
```

If a change is made to s1 it triggers an api call that retrieves valid options for s2 and s3 and changes the link for the button.  Similarly, if s2 is changed the combination of the selection in s1 and s2 determine the options in s3.

Basically it works to have the forms use the same reducers and actions but just have a different URL depending on the API endpoint passed to the form via a prop.

The question is, does it make more sense to have these be 3 seperate stores via the store key passed to the react-redux connect or should these be in the same store, but then register a top level reducer based on some unique ID?

So 3 stores with the following top level data structure

```
{
  selected: { [field: string]: string }
  options: { field: string]: string[] }
}
```

Or something like one store and each form registers a reducer with the `formId`?

```
{
  [formId: string]: {
    selected: { [field: string]: string },
    options: { field: string]: string[] }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up handling this using a unique key for each form, and keeping all the forms in the same top level store.

I have a main ModuleReducer that has an registerModule action.  This action triggers a key to be added to the store.  The main thing is that every action flows through the module reducer and if it isn't a module action it then gets passed down to other reducers for the specific key.

Here is a simplified sample of the code.

```
interface FormOptions {
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface FormValues {
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface ModuleState {
  options: FormOptions;
  selectedValues: FormValues;
}

interface AppStore {
  [id: string]: ModuleState;
}

const moduleReducer = (state: AppStore = {}, { type, payload }: AnyAction) => {
  const { formId } = payload;
  switch (type) {
    case 'REGISTER':
      return {
        ...state,
        [formId]: { options: {}, selectedValues: {} }
      };
    default:
      const { options, selectedValues, ...restState } = state[formId];
      return {
        ...state,
        [formId]: {
          ...restState,
          options: optionsReducer(options, ({ type, payload })),
          selectedValues: valueReducer(selectedValues, ({ type, payload }))
        }
      };
  }
}
```

I ultimately decided on doing it this way, in the event that the forms reference common values in the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing of state is one of the roles of reducers. Applications should generally only have one global store. In your case you want to split the state for each of your three forms, so it makes more sense to create one or more reducers for this. If each form's state is closely related to one another then your approach with one reducer is fine, but for unrelated data consider creating multiple reducers, and using the combineReducers function.

Comment: Combine reducers was the initial approach but was not suitable for solving the problem.  Redux Forms was more closely what was wanted to mimic but was overkill.